# Connect NiFi to MS SQL server windows 10

Tags: java, apache-nifi

I am not able to connect nifi using sql server can you please help me getting below error

```
Error 
00:52:36 ISTERRORcf6cf1cb-0173-1000-1496-523d316e3cff
ExecuteSQL[id=cf6cf1cb-0173-1000-1496-523d316e3cff] ExecuteSQL[id=cf6cf1cb-0173-1000-1496-523d316e3cff] failed to process session due to Cannot invoke method public default java.sql.Connection org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPService.getConnection(java.util.Map) throws org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException on Controller Service with identifier cf674d7f-0173-1000-ce58-0312a249a0df because the Controller Service's State is currently ENABLING; Processor Administratively Yielded for 1 sec: org.apache.nifi.controller.service.ControllerServiceDisabledException: Cannot invoke method public default java.sql.Connection org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPService.getConnection(java.util.Map) throws org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException on Controller Service with identifier cf674d7f-0173-1000-ce58-0312a249a0df because the Controller Service's State is currently ENABLING
```

Database Connection URL: **jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=DB_NAME;integratedSecurity=true;**
Database Driver Class Name **com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver**
Database Driver Location(s) **file:///C:/Users/user_name/sqljdbc_8.4/enu/mssql-jdbc-8.4.0.jre8.jar**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The controller service's state is "ENABLING" which means the service is not available yet. Refresh the UI and when that service is available, you can start the processor that relies on it.

Comment: Andy thanks for replay  controller service's available